# Unity Interface weird font display

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just installed unity3d and it seems that I have a pretty weird problem with the fonts inside the unity interface.. I was watching some tutorials and there was no problem for the person who I was following.
Here's what I am talking about:

[image]

Take a look at the fonts in the General secion or from Favorites, they look really weird and kinda hard to read..
Is it from my graphic card or something? (I've got an ATI R9 280)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you should circle what the problem is then re-upload the picture. I currently see nothing wrong in the picture..

Comment: Did you click on the picture to see it fullscreen? Font looks hard to read to me.. Not pixelated or something but it's like some letters have like a grey-white color around them and makes it hard to read. Maybe it's just me? Please take a look fullscreen.

Comment: Ok, I think it might be from the monitor that I have.. When I stand up and look at it the text is normal.. Can be from the brightness or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out my problem. The problem was with my monitor so if you're text in unity looks hard to read, like it has some greyish-white in some letters or generally doesn't look sharp make sure that you're monitor "Sharpness" option is not set too high. I set mine to 5 and now everything looks sharp.